# Typescript import from .d.ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, angular

I wrote a (at this point) simple components for angular2.

Here's my code so far:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';

export module SkApp.Core{
  @Component({
    selector: 'sk-app-side-menu'
   })
  @View({
    template: `
        <p>Hello</p>
    `
  })
  export class SkAppSideMenu {
    menuActive: boolean;

    constructor(){

      this.menuActive = false;
    }


    showMenu(){

      this.menuActive = !this.menuActive;

    }
  }
}
```

Of course there's no real functionality at this point. But that's not the point right now.

I also created my own build process with gulp. Here's the relevant part of it:

```
gulp.task('script', ['clean'], function() {
    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
      .pipe(ts(tsProject));

      return merge([ 
       tsResult.dts.pipe(rename({dirname: ''}))
       .pipe(concat('sk-app.d.ts'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/')),
       tsResult.js
       .pipe(rename({dirname: ''}))
       .pipe(concat('sk-app.min.js'))
       .pipe(uglify())
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))

   ]);
});
```

At the end I get two files: sk-app.min.js and sk-app.d.ts

sk-app.min.js:

```
var __decorate=this&&this.__decorate||function(t,e,n,r){if("object"==typeof Reflect&&"function"==typeof Reflect.decorate)return Reflect.decorate(t,e,n,r);switch(arguments.length){case 2:return t.reduceRight(function(t,e){return e&&e(t)||t},e);case 3:return t.reduceRight(function(t,r){return void(r&&r(e,n))},void 0);case 4:return t.reduceRight(function(t,r){return r&&r(e,n,t)||t},r)}},__metadata=this&&this.__metadata||function(t,e){return"object"==typeof Reflect&&"function"==typeof Reflect.metadata?Reflect.metadata(t,e):void 0},angular2_1=require("angular2/angular2"),SkApp;!function(t){var e;!function(t){var e=function(){function t(){}return t.prototype.showMenu=function(t){},t=__decorate([angular2_1.Component({selector:"sk-app"}),angular2_1.View({template:'\n        <button (click)="showMenu()">click me!</button>\n\n        <ng-content></ng-content>\n      ',directives:[angular2_1.NgClass]}),__metadata("design:paramtypes",[])],t)}();t.SkApp=e}(e=t.Core||(t.Core={}))}(SkApp=exports.SkApp||(exports.SkApp={}));
```

sk-app.d.ts:

```
export declare module SkApp.Core {
    class SkApp {
        showMenu(x: string): void;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this component within another angular2 project:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {SkApp} from "SkApp/Core";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
    template: '<sk-app></sk-app>',
    directives: [SkApp]
})
class MyAppComponent {

}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

But when I try to compile this project to js the typescript compiler gives me this message:

error TS2307: Cannot find module 'SkApp/Core'

When I change the module-definition within my sk-app.d.ts file to:

```
declare module "SkApp/Core" {
```

it works fine. But I want to have my definition files to be generated by gulp without having to change the module declaration myself.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

(Of course I am aware, that angular2 is still in alpha state)

Answer (score 0):

> export module SkApp.Core{
>   I think it should be:

```
 module SkApp.Core {...
```

Since for what I know, Typescript doesn't have module level visibility modifiers